# How to setup RabbitMQ cluster with AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

Followed this article
https://medium.com/@vipin.pratap18/rabbitmq-cluster-on-aws-ec2-with-high-availability-1bcd3f8a6404

But while doing sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@

facing issue

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: [rabbit@rabbitmqnode1]

rabbit@rabbitmqnode1:

- connected to epmd (port 4369) on rabbitmqnode1
- epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
- TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
- Node name (or hostname) mismatch: node "rabbit@ip-xxxxx" believes its node name is not "rabbit@ip-xxxxx" but something else.
  All nodes and CLI tools must refer to node "rabbit@ip-10-0-1-122" using the same name the node itself uses (see its logs to find out what it is)

Comment: The last line of the output gives a suggestion on how to proceed. Have you linked into it?

Comment: no, any guidance from scratch would be helpful I am new to this

Comment: Well, it tells you to look at the logs on the other server to find its node name. Is there some reason you can't do that?

Comment: yes I can do that, I have been doing that since past 4 hours the nodes name are correct, both nodes erlang cookie are same but again some issue saying
the system not allowed to use fully qualified hostname I have tried that using the combinations 10.20.3.139 , IP-10.20.3.139, ip-10.20.3.139.us.west.internal always getting same error so I'm confused with this generic error.


thats why opting for a set of guidelines or checklist where I am missing.

Comment: I understand that it's frustrating, but remember we can only see the information that you show us, so if you've already spent hours trying to solve the problem, you need to include a summary of that in your question - what is the configuration you've been editing, what have you seen in the logs, and so on. There's an [edit] button under the question, please try to include as much information as you can, so that we don't all waste time talking about things you've already looked at.

Comment: i try using docker and EB, but nodes not intro to cluster, i don't have ideia why(question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612706/deploy-rabbitmq-docker-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk, someone  can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by following the logs itself

it clearly says "CLI tools must refer to node "rabbit@ip-10-0-x-xxx" using the same name the node itself uses"

while passing the cluster node name i was doing it wrong
NOTE : added hostname from cat /etc/hosts

did like below
sudo rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@ip-10-0-x-yyy

and it worked
suucessfull message "Clustering node rabbit@ip-10-0-x-xxx with rabbit@ip-10-0-x-yyy"